# Audacity: Show track names in compact view

Tags: audacity

## My Problem

I am using audacity to merge multiple short audio files to a log one, with some overlaps. The tracks disaply their waveform, which is not important to me, but without their name (that appears on the far left).

[image: Audacity tracks view]

I've seen audacity [screenshots](https://twitter.com/ohcybermycyber/status/1247645030958989314) in which the track name appears instead of the waveform, which makes editing way easier for my use case.

## What Have I Tried

I Googled "Compact view" and alike, and browsed the menus.

## My Question

How can I view the tracks names without their waveform in Audacity, [like this example](https://twitter.com/ohcybermycyber/status/1247645030958989314) ?

Comment: Hello. What you can see in the linked capture is a label track https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/label_tracks.html

Comment: Thanks. Care to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not sure that it will solve your issue, the screen capture you are linking to :

[image: Screen capture from Twitter user @ohcybermycyber]

*Screen capture from Twitter user @ohcybermycyber*

actually shows a [label track](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/label_tracks.html) :

[image: Screen from Audacity documentation]

*Screen from Audacity documentation*